# Calculate BLOB size using triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to calculate the Blob size of a table using triggers.

This is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'test' BEFORE INSERT ON 'mytable'
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.blobsize = LENGHT(new.blobfile);
```

but i recive the following error

```
FUNCTION dbname.LENGHT does not exist
```

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are after is [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_length).  Note that is is spelled `TH`, not `HT` (which is what you currently have):

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'test' BEFORE INSERT ON 'mytable'
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.blobsize = LENGTH(new.blobfile);
```

Comment: @VeNoMiS: That's for you to do... :)